# How to perform specific operations during installating or updating a TideSDK app?

Tags: tidesdk

I went thru the docs but couldn't find how can I perform specific operations when app is being installed or when app is being updated.

What I want to do is, create table when app is being installed and if in future, db schema changes, I want to perform those operations when app is being updated.

Answer (score 1):

According to me .. the best place to do these changes are in the code. so whenever the application starts up first time after getting updated.. you do all the db schema changes.

This makes sure that your application is fully updated before you touch any database and secondly u do not have to write any special logic separately while installing / updating the application.

Comment: I was looking for more specific events to which my Code can subscribe.

So whenever that event occurs I can do required stuff.
Eg. Event.AppInstalled

so when that even is triggered, I can create all the required tables. And hence I don't have to check every time whether tables are created or not.

Comment: This can easily be served by adding a key in key-value store and checking the flag every time u start ur app. no need to check every single table updated or not etc.